# Set JS variable when clicking on polygon in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I have a MapBox map (created using TileMill) with about 800 polygons (census tracts). I've loaded the map onto an HTML page. Also on this page is a D3.js chart. There is a drop-down menu that references those same 800 census tracts; when one is selected, the chart changes to show the data from that row in the CSV file (built from a D3.js [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848)).

What I need to do, and cannot find a way to do, is make this map so that when the tract (polygon) is clicked on the map, it updates the variable (the tract is named "TRACTCE10" in the map) so that the chart also changes. I think this can be done by either updating the dropdown list (which I can then hide later on), or by directly changing the variable within the D3 javascript.

The latest method I tried was suggested by MapBox support but does not work:

`map.gridLayer.on('mousemove',function() { dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get(this.TRACTCE10)); });`

This is the full code:

```
<div class="infobar">Info
    <div class="chart">
      <h1>Vehicle Ownership</h1>
        <div id="va_chart"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="TRACTCE10"></div>
  </div>
        <script>

var dispatch = d3.dispatch("load", "tractchange");

var groups = [
  "0 vehicles",
  "1 vehicle",
  "2 vehicles",
  "3+ vehicles"
];

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, tracts) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var tractById = d3.map();
  tracts.forEach(function(d) { tractById.set(d.id, d); });
  dispatch.load(tractById);
  dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get("010100"));
});

// Drop-down menu for selecting a tract; uses the "menu" namespace.
dispatch.on("load.menu", function(tractById) {
  var select = d3.select("#va_chart")
    .append("div")
    .append("select")
      .on("change", function() { dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get(this.value)); });

  select.selectAll("option")
      .data(tractById.values())
    .enter().append("option")
      .attr("value", function(d) { return d.id; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  dispatch.on("tractchange.menu", function(state) {
    select.property("value", state.id);
  });
});

// A pie chart to show population by age group; uses the "pie" namespace.
dispatch.on("load.pie", function(tractById) {
  var width = 200,
      height = 200,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 1.9;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(groups)
      .range(["#fdbb84", "#fc8d59", "#e34a33", "#b30000"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 50)
      .innerRadius(radius - 10);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null);

  var svg = d3.select("#va_chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(groups)
    .enter().append("path")
      .style("fill", color)
      .each(function() { this._current = {startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}; });

  dispatch.on("tractchange.pie", function(d) {
    path.data(pie.value(function(g) { return d[g]; })(groups)).transition()
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
          var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
          this._current = interpolate(0);
          return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
          };
        });
  });
});

// Coerce population counts to numbers and compute total per state.
function type(d) {
  d.total = d3.sum(groups, function(k) { return d[k] = +d[k]; });
  return d;
}

var ddl = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
ddl.setAttribute("id", "ddlinput");

</script>
```

And the Mapbox JS:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'transitized.68dk8798');

  map.gridLayer
    .on('mousemove',function() { dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get(this.TRACTCE10)); });


</script>
```

The full code can be found on github: https://github.com/shaunjacobsen/chicagocommutes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
map.gridLayer
  .on('mousemove',function() { dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get(this.TRACTCE10)); });
```

Leaflet doesn't do the this == data metaphor - do

```
map.gridLayer
  .on('mousemove',function(e) { dispatch.tractchange(tractById.get(e.data.TRACTCE10)); });
```

Instead

Comment: I'm confused because that still doesn't change the value that is represented in the graph. I understand now that Leaflet handles it differently, but the census tract ID is still not being updated to reflect the click.